# bug (?) codeigniter crop image height and width changed

Tags: php, codeigniter, gd

i sent `source_image`, `x_axis`, `y_axis`, `height`, and `width` from UI to process image (in this case i crop an image), here's my code:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$image = $this->input->post('source_image');
//array configuration for clock-wise and counter-clock-wise
$angle = array(
        0 => 0,
        90 => 270,
        180 => 180,
        270 => 90
    );

    $rotation = $this->input->post('rotation');
    $x = $this->input->post('x');
    $y = $this->input->post('y');
    $width = $this->input->post('width');
    $height = $this->input->post('height');

    $result = array();

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $image;
    $config['x_axis'] = $x;
    $config['y_axis'] = $y;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = $width;
    $config['height'] = $height;

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->image_lib->crop()) {
        $result = array(
        'result' => FALSE,
        'error' => $this->image_lib->display_errors()
        );
    }
```

when i finish cropping image and then i checked again the resolution it changes, for ex:

`width: 197px;
height: 173px;`

it should be that resolution when i finished cropping, but when i checked it the resolution changed to

`width: 181px;
height: 173px;`

in other case, sometimes the width changing sometimes the height changing either..

am i wrong when configuring the `$config` or anything? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you shouldn't use `$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;` (set it to false).

> Since the maintain_ratio option is enabled, the image will be as close
>   to the target width and height as possible while *preserving* the
>   **original aspect ratio**.

Docs: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#processing-an-image

Keep in mind, changing the ratio or setting it to false so that the sizes are hard values will cause some images to skew or look weird. CI doesn't have a way of really handling this but there are other upload libraries out there that can add black bars or so while maintaining your specified sizes such as: https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php

Comment: @yosafat ksatria can you provide your crop code of UI/html side, from where you have given the crop input.?